# Same code but different colors in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7-statusbar

i set background color of status bar using code below

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
{
    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 20)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(31.0/255.0) green:(109.0/255.0) blue:(128.0/255.0) alpha:1];
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:view];
}
```

Also I set background color of my View in storyboard to exactly same color (R:31,G:109,B:128). But in result colors aren't same. Background color in status bar is brighter than in View.

In Info.plist I have `Status bar style` set to `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` and `View controller-based status bar appearance` set to `NO`.

Is that because status bar is translucent?
How can I change that?
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, change navigationbar state to opaque:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Comment: self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

Comment: Thanks for answer, but there is no navigation bar, only status bar and view. When I set up navigation bar everything is OK, but I don't want navigation bar there. I would attach printscreen but I don't have enough reputation points...